# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' - after multiplying two columns

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I'm new to Python and I wish to understand why I get this error

I am trying to obtain the result into a new column (called Sum) of: 'Quantity Ordered' multiplied by 'Price Each'.

I get the error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str' and I don't understand why, do you know why?

I have done the following:

```
import pandas as pd

files = ["Sales_January_2019.csv", 
         "Sales_February_2019.csv",
         "Sales_March_2019.csv",
         "Sales_April_2019.csv",
         "Sales_May_2019.csv",
         "Sales_June_2019.csv",
         "Sales_July_2019.csv",
         "Sales_August_2019.csv",
         "Sales_September_2019.csv",
         "Sales_October_2019.csv",
         "Sales_November_2019.csv",
         "Sales_December_2019.csv"]

df = pd.DataFrame()
for name in files:
    tmp = pd.read_csv(name, index_col=0)
    df = df.append(tmp)
    
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.drop(['x_t', 'perf'], axis=1)
print(df)

print(df['Order Date'])
df['Month'] = df['Order Date'].str[0:2]
print(df['Month'])

#df['Month'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Month']) 

liste_av_mndsnr = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12']
month_filter = (df['Month'].isin(liste_av_mndsnr))

df = df[month_filter] 
print(df['Month'])
print(df)

df ['Sum'] = df['Quantity Ordered'] * df['Price Each'] 
df.head()
print (df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed by

```
df ['Quantity Ordered'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Quantity Ordered'])
df ['Price Each'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Price Each'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the 'Quantity Ordered' and 'Price each' column types? This may be due to the column type 'str'.

If this is the case, you can convert the type of each column like this:

```
df['Quantity Ordered'] = df['Quantity Ordered'].astype('int')
df['Price Each'] = df['Price Each'].astype('float')
```